# How to dynamically change the css style of a particular item inside a map function

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I currently have two map functions to render a board for a chess game like this:

```
        <div className='board'>
            {rows.map((item) => (
                <div key={item} className='row'>
                    {item.map((square) => (
# The square <div> =>  <div key={square[0]} className='square' onClick={() => {
                            board.select !== null &&
                            checkColour(board.select[1]) !== checkColour(square[1]) && dispatch(move(square))
                        }}>
                            {isNaN(square[1]) && <img src={square[1]} alt={square[1]}
                                onClick={() => { board.turns === checkColour(square[1]) && dispatch(select(square)) }}
                                className={board.select === square ? 'piece-selected' : 'piece'} />}
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
```

[image]

Now, I want to change the css style of certain squares `<div>` after I selected a pawn piece in order to forecast a shadow for showing the possible moves. I want to know is it possible to access the css style of that particular square `<div>` using the `key` of that `<div>`?

Feel free the drop a comment below if you have any insight or idea. Let me know if you want more info. Much appreciated.

Comment: You can dynamically have class names added or removed. Based on this you can define the CSS differences in those classes

Comment: Maybe it is easier to use indexes of squares ? I mean depending on the piece selected, the possible moves can be defined as a simple addition or substraction. For example a bishop can go ```ìnitialSquare±n*col±n*row``` which can be ```ìnitialSquare±n*7``` or ```ìnitialSquare±n*9``` in your array of squares.